# How to add a newly created user in artifactory when sync with LDAP

Tags: artifactory

May I know how we can add an account into artifactory when it is synchronizing with LDAP. Do we need to add manually or will it be get synchronized automatically when a new user is created in LDAP. thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Artifactory User Guide - Managing Security with LDAP](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Security+with+LDAP):

> Artifactory supports authenticating users against an LDAP server out-of-the-box.
>
> When LDAP authentication is active, Artifactory first attempts to authenticate the user against the LDAP server. If LDAP authentication fails, Artifactory tries to authenticate via its internal database.
>
> For every LDAP authenticated user Artifactory creates a new user in the internal database (provided the user does not already exist), and automatically assigns that user to the default groups.

HTH,
Yinon

Comment: Yes, after creating user in AD/LDAP first user needs to get login into artifactory for first time and then user can be visible in artifactory to assign some repo permissions. so, a user even created in LDAP/AD needs to login in artifactory.